# Error NSAttributedString al cambiar a Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift2, swift3

Tengo este código que sirve para convertir este tipo de caracteres: `simb&oacute;lica` a esto: `simbólica`.

```
do {
      let encodedData = actualLabel.text!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
      let attributedOptions: [String: AnyObject] = [
          NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType as AnyObject,
          NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8 as AnyObject
      ]
      let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
          actualLabel.text = attributedString.string
} catch {
   fatalError("Unhandled error: \(error)")
}
```

En `swift 2.0` funcionaba correctamente. Pero en swift 3 me devuelve este error y no me dejar seguir con la ejecución de la app.

```
-[_SwiftValue unsignedIntegerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17404f210
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue unsignedIntegerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17404f210'
```

Haciendo el debug, he llegado hasta la linea en la que da error, que concretamente es:

```
let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like

```
let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
```

Comment: Aparte de traducir, podrias agregar detalles del porque este codigo funciona :)